# Magento 1.9.2. - Save the attribute of the customer_account table in the form customer_address

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, customer, customer-address

On the customer address change page I am trying to add fields for some `custom attributes` that I have created and inserted into the `customer_account` table.

After several tests I saw that in the **edit.phtml** form of the Magento client address change only saves the attributes present in the `customer_address` table.

> How can I make sure that the form also contains attributes that are
>   present in the **customer_account** table?

**Thank you**

Comment: yiu have custom create table `customer_account`?

Comment: No, I mean the magento default table. I don't have any custom tables.

Comment: i have checked magento default table structure but not available `customer_account` table

Comment: Ok, maybe I wrote wrong. What I'd like to know is if there is an action for the form to save all the customer attributes in frontend. At the moment in the Magento address change form, use the action: $this->getSaveUrl()

Comment: but you want what exactly? here mate

Comment: When I am in "edit address" of the client I would like to be able to save also other customer attributes besides those of the address, for example email address.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91807/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-gabriel91).